# How to post something to Facebook from Android?

Tags: android, facebook

Quick questions here:
What are the necessary tools/APIs to post something from Android to Facebook?
I looked at this URL
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:Android

and it mentioned a few suggestions.
Have anyone tried fbrocket?
What is Facebook Connect anyway?

Thanks!

Nicholas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) necessarily makes use of HTTP for all communication.

There are implementations of the Facebook API for a [number of languages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/).

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. I'll investigate this further.

Answer (score 6):

Don't integrate Facebook API from mobile.

Instead you should create your own web service and put somewhere on the web where you can update API changes more frequently than rolling out new mobile version of your app for each API changes. So the point here is that you keep API calls on the webserver where you can do immediate changes rather than pushing mobile updates through time consuming Markets approval.

Make that go (1) Android phone -> (2) your webserver file with Facebook API --> (3) Facebook Servers. You can find more examples working with Facebook API such as using PHP.

Comment: How do you create your own web service?